# How to query Metadata Query

Tags: soql, metadata

I want to query newly created fields(Metadata) in the contact object where day = `Today()`.

Is this possible in Salesforce?

Answer (score 3):

Querying metadata level information is not yet possible natively in SOQL or Apex.

You can use [Apex Wrapper for the Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) by [Andrew Fawcett](http://twitter.com/andyinthecloud). With that it should be possible.